# Sequence of solutions of approximated problem converging to stationary solution of the original problem

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, optimization

Let $I(x)$ be the indicator function defined as $$I(x) \triangleq \begin{cases} 1, & x \geq 0 \\ 0, & x < 0 \end{cases}$$ and let $L(x,\alpha) \in [0,1]$ be a smoothing function that approximates $I(x)$, with $$\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow + \infty} L(x,\alpha) = I(x), \quad \forall x$$ $$\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty} L(x,\alpha) = 0, \quad \forall \alpha$$ $$\lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} L(x,\alpha) = 1, \quad \forall \alpha.$$

Now, let $\underline{x}, \overline{x}$ be fixed parameters with $0 < \underline{x} < \overline{x}$; let $\mathcal{Q}$ be some convex set and let $f(x)$ be a convex function in $\mathcal{X}$. I have the following two problems (original and approximated, respectively):

$$ \begin{array}{cll}
\min_{x} & & f(x) + I(x-\underline{x}) \\
\mathrm{s.t.} & & x \in \mathcal{Q} \hspace{4cm} (P) \\
 & & I(x-\underline{x}) \underline{x} \leq x \leq I(x-\underline{x}) \overline{x}
\end{array}$$

$$ \begin{array}{cll}
\min_{x} & & f(x) + L(x-\underline{x}, \alpha) \\
\mathrm{s.t.} & & x \in \mathcal{Q} \hspace{4cm} (P_{\alpha}) \\
 & & L(x-\underline{x},\alpha) \underline{x} \leq x \leq L(x-\underline{x},\alpha) \overline{x}
\end{array}$$

If $v(\cdot)$ denotes the optimal solution of problem $(\cdot)$, how can I demonstrate the following? $$\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow + \infty} v(P_{\alpha}) = v(P)$$
In other words, how can I demonstrate that the sequence of solutions of the approximated problem $P_{\alpha}$ converges to a stationary solution of the original problem $P$ as $\alpha \rightarrow + \infty$?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sequence of solutions of approximated problem converging to stationary solution of the original problems](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693989/sequence-of-solutions-of-approximated-problem-converging-to-stationary-solution)

Comment: To be sure I understand, the constraint $$I(x-\underline{x}) \underline{x} \leq x \leq I(x-\underline{x}) \overline{x}$$ requires exactly $$x\in\{0\}\cup [\underline{x},\overline{x}],$$ right?

Comment: That's exactly it.